# Can you instantiate all windows immediately upon opening your project?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have one form that I initially load(login), after that window, is the main window where everything is controlled.  What I'm curious about is is there a way to create instances of all the forms I need(on demand, will not create ALL forms in case not all are used in the same session).

I'm running into an issue where I would like to use a 'common' class that has functions that all windows can use but I'm not sure how I'm able to instantiate an object of the common class, and access that class throughout the session, holding all data throughout all the forms.

Example:

Main window loads, we instantiate the common class and run through some functions to hold some data to be used throughout the main window, but if I click on a button that opens a new form, that form will not have access to the common class unless I instantiate it there however doing this I lose all data that was held in that common class.

Am I missing something?  Will I be able to instantiate the common class(or any of the form) only once and not have to re-instantiate the classes or forms thus losing all information I had 'saved'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Common Class` sounds like it needs to either be a `singleton`, or you need to pass a reference to it around between forms.

The singleton pattern will make sure that there is only ever one reference.  Some people might consider using a singleton this way as a `code-smell`, but its probably the easiest way to do what you want.  See [Here](http://vbnotebookfor.net/2007/09/13/introduction-to-the-singleton-pattern-in-vbnet/) for an example of making a singlton in vb.net.

Passing a reference around is probably the better approach, but is slightly more complicated.

Comment: OK I understand what you are saying, this is part of the question as well.  Upon loading the Main window, I can instantiate the common class, all is well here.  Once I open a new window, to 'talk' to the main window, i'd have to instantiate the Main window thus re-instantiating the common class, removing any data that was in there.  Am I doing this incorrect?

Comment: A singleton can't be instantiated more than once.  Every reference to it, no matter how you get it, will always point to the exact same instance.  If you place properties on the singleton you can place values from form1 and retrieve them from form2.  You shouln't have to create a new instance of the main window from the 2nd window just to talk to it.